# Suggestions for the placement of decoupling and filtering components

Tags: reed-switch

The following diagram depicts a circuit intended for activation via reed switches. Q1 is normally conducting through the voltage divider R1 and R2. With Q1 conducting, Q2 is biased off (non-conducting) via R3 and R4. The SCR remains non-conducting. When the magnetic reed switch opens, Q1 no longer conducts, after which C1 discharges into the base of Q2 via R3, which causes Q2 to conduct. The SCR receives current through C1,R5 and R6 and it activates the relay. I'd like to know whether this circuit benefits from filtering components, considering the reed switches (window contacts) [image]are connected via long wires to the circuit and might need components to remove RF and other sources that might induce noise into the circuit.

I was thinking of adding a reverse diode (or TVS) before the first voltage divider. Also, adding 100nF cap at base of Q1. Please share your suggestions.

Comment: You sure think up some odd circuits.. The cap on Q1 is a good idea, so is the TVS. What everything between the collector of Q1 and R6 is for seems overkill. I'd just tie the collector to the gate of that SCR and tie the left end of R6 to Vcc which I assume is also 9V.

Comment: Yu also need a way to turn it off/bypass it.

Comment: btw "You sure think up some odd circuits.." was not a bad comment, just interesting.

Comment: Hi Trevor, thanks for the suggestion. If I connect the left end of R6 to VCC, wouldn't the SCR always be on?

Comment: Not with the transistor Q1 on the gate pulling it down...no

Comment: But you DO need a switch in the relay line so you can disable it once it is on.

Comment: Yes, I'll include a switch, thanks. Also, what doe you think of a 100pF cap before the first voltage divider, connecting the loop to ground for high frequencies?

Comment: It does seem like an unusually complicated way of doing it. In good circuit design, every single part must be justified or not be there. I would have your 9 V signal driving an RC low-pass filter (series R into C to GND) to remove transients/noise then into your SCR. I would want to have to pull a decent current through the switch for a trigger to happen, at least 1 mA, so that radiated noise couldn't do it. I imagine the SCR will require more than that, anyway.

Comment: NO point putting the cap before the divider since the R component of RC would be close to zero. On the base of Q1 is the spot.

Comment: @ Trevor yes, there is no resistor on that patch. I might put it parallel to 100nF cap on the base Q1.

Comment: @TonyM there will be one or two caps on the base of Q1, this makes low pass filter. The SCR is actually sensitive gate type. According to data sheet the gate trigger current is 200uA max.

Comment: Hi Baphomet, consider taking your 9 V into a 3-resistor potential divider of Ru, Rm and Rl (upper, middle, lower). Junction of Ru/Rm has a filter cap C to GND on. Junction of Rm/Rl drives the SCR gate. Sum of resistors is 1800 R so it draws 5 mA, making to disturbance of supplying the 200 uA to SCR around a 4 % swing i.e. negligible enough. (Ru+Rm):Rl chosen to meet SCR gate voltage. Ru=2xRm or thereabouts. C chosen to require 200 ms signal charging time before triggering SCR. (Sorry I can't draw this, on a mobile screen.)

Comment: @TonyM Ok thanks, but I don't understand how the last part about the capacitor is related to the posted circuit. Do you mean the chosen value for C1 should meet the SCR 200uA or you'r referring to the low pass cap (not shown) on base of Q1?

Comment: I meant I'd throw away your circuit except the SCR and battery and add the parts I described. Sorry I can't draw a schematic now, try sketching it up :-)

Comment: I understand your circuit, the problem is the 1800R total resistance would kill the battery quickly. I have several simple designs based on SCR, Mosfet and logic gates. The question was how and where to place the filtering components in the above circuit or other suggestions regarding the improvement of the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

BTW: you can make a simple alarm with just the right relay and a couple of switches. When armed the relay is pulled in.

Not really battery friendly though since the coil is draining current all the time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPSXTO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or a fancier version....

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLRV8I.png)</sup>

Comment: It's simple and efficient design. It would be good for the mains powered circuits.

Comment: Is it self latching?

Comment: yes, since the relay itself is in the switch loop.